Cassandra Heap Size Setup for G1GC
According to official documents, it is recommended to set Cassandra max heap size as large as possible up to 64G for G1. Any reason why we are doing this? Does more heap size means better gc performance, etc. shorter pause/less frequent gc?
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsTuneJVM.html

It entirely depends on the application. If you have more heap, you could see fewer gc pauses, but with that comes the possibility of longer gc pauses. Also, your gc pauses can get long if the allocation survives to Old Gen.
Most typically, I see 31GiB of the heap. If you start seeing long gc pauses due to things like humongous object allocations, you can increase the heap and the region size. Ideally, you keep your objects (single cells) small, under 4MiB, which will work with 31GiB of memory.
Also, I expressly set it to 31GiB, not 32GiB, because there are some instances where the memory will be set to more than the allowed for OOP compression. You want to maintain compression.
You can use this to check at which point object pointer compression ends with your version of Java:
java -Xmx32767M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompressedOopsMode -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~16.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
Optimized Ordinary Pointers enabled:

